# How do I use a variable to specify a path to exclude in `find`?

Tags: bash, quoting

I'm trying to use a variable to specify an exclusion path in the `find` command.

This snippet works:

```
x="*test/.util/*"
y="*test/sh/*"

find test -type f -name "*.sh" -not -path "$x" -not -path "$y"
```

But I'd like to move `-not -path` into the variables, as in:

```
x="-not -path *test/.util/*"
y="-not -path *test/sh/*"

# error: find: -not -path *test/.util/*: unknown primary or operator
find test -type f -name "*.sh" "$x" "$y"

# Tried removing quotes
# error: find: test/.util/foo.sh: unknown primary or operator
find test -type f -name "*.sh" $x $y
```

I also tried adding quotes to the paths in the variables, but that results in no path filtering.

```
# no syntax error but does not exclude the paths
x="-not -path '*test/.util/*'"
y="-not -path '*test/sh/*'"
```

I'm using OSX Mavericks; GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13).

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: @chepner's answer is entirely correct and on-point. You might also see BashFAQ #50: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`find` is receiving `-not -path *test/.util/*` as a single argument, not as 3 separate arguments that it requires. You can use an array instead.

```
x=(-not -path "*test/.util/*")
y=(-not -path "*test/sh/*")

find test -type f -name "*.sh" "${x[@]}" "${y[@]}"
```

When quoted, `${x[@]}` expands into a series of separate words, one per array element, and each word remains properly quoted, so the patterns are passed literally, as intended, to `find`.